# Migration of a stand alone Flex Application / WindowedApplication into Box or Group

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flash-builder

In order to integrate several Air Applications into one.

I tried the way by migration the old `<s:WindowedApplication>` / `<s:Application>` into `<s:Group>` or `<mx:Box>`.

By doing this I found out that the initialization order of MXML components nested in the new Group / Box differs from the one in Application. In consequence I got null pointer exceptions when I instantiate this new Group / Box.

Any ideas? Comments?

Comment: In which methods do these exceptions occure?

Comment: One CaseTypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at modules.ilog::projecteditor/activeViewChanged()[C:\SVN\workspace_fb_45\Modul-Prototypen\xxx\src\modules\ilog\projecteditor.mxml:885]
 at modules.ilog::projecteditor/viewStack_valueCommitHandler()[C:\SVN\workspace_fb_45\Modul-Prototypen\xxx\src\modules\ilog\projecteditor.mxml:858]
 at modules.ilog::projecteditor/__viewStack_valueCommit() which is called automatically at startup

Comment: If you wrote some of theses methods could you provide some code?

Comment: "initialization order of mxml components nested in the new Group / Box differs from the one in Application" I find this hard to believe.  In MXML components should be instantiated in the order they appear (from top to bottom).  Without seeing code, it is hard to guess what the real problem is.

Comment: I think you're just trying to reference Application or WindowedApplication somewhere in your child components (which you shouldn't do in the first place).  Show the code so we can debug.

Comment: i try to integrate http://visunetdemos.demos.ibm.com/ganttdemos/projecteditor/projecteditor.html i think the problem here is that it might be compiled earlier with flex 3 and i heard from some senior developers that they changed the initialization order from flex 3 to flex 4

Comment: SkinnableContainer is an extension of UIComponent from what I've heard and seen the component life cycle has not changed significantly with the exception of a few new events/methods pertaining to when skin parts are added or removed.  You should run in debug mode and link up the source as much as possible look using the trace window in eclipse (or your IDE of choice) and see what value is null and where it is originating from.

Comment: i got this first error <!-- TODO valueCommit="viewStack_valueCommitHandler(event)" -->
<mx:ViewStack id="viewStack" width="100%" height="100%">

in about Line 1508 of the example. It seems that in Flex 4.5 at least the valueCommit is also activated in creation process and because of a top down initialization. The indirecly influence children of the ViewStack are not initialized.

top-down initialization-> valueCommitHandler->activeViewChange-> switch case block for exampel case 0 adressese, _activeGanttChart = taskChart; But the taskChart is not initialized at this point